# Perl: oo with use parent - checking if class has a parent

Tags: perl

I have some Perl objects which were built some time ago not with Moose,
but with bless, inheritance is implemented using the 'parent' pragma.

Now I would like to know whether there is a way to check whether a certain class has used 'parent' or not.

e.g. if I have two classes

```
package Animal;
sub new { 
   my $class = shift;
   return bless {}, $class;
}
1;
```

and

```
package Cat;
use parent 'Animal';

sub new { 
   my $class = shift;
   return bless {}, $class;
}
1;
```

would there be some check I could make to determine that the 'Cat' class 
has a parent ( do not care which, but not itself ), and Animal does not, given a $foo which is either of them?

Comment: Yes, but I'm reluctant to tell you about it because I'm afraid you're going to use it for evil.

Comment: I certainly will. Please?

Comment: I am using Moose nowadays for OO-related, but I do not want to redo this.

Comment: What possible use could you have for that kind of check?

Comment: some methods of children call SUPER methods that need attributes that are not set. So in new, I want to check if there is a parent, so I can let it set those needed attributes if necessary. Perhaps I have misunderstood something, but that was my first idea to approach this instead of having to edit all parent or child classes that potentially cause this problem. But it is unnecessary if there is no parent.

Comment: Whose `new` are we talking about? If you're writing a class, you already know if you're inheriting from anything.

Comment: Also, now that I have thought of it, I want to know how to do it, I guess...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87092/discussion-between-bytepusher-and-melpomene).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't picture why you'd ever want to know this, but it's possible using the following:

```
use mro;
my $inherits = @{ mro::get_linear_isa($class) } > 1;
```

or

```
my $isa = do { no strict 'refs'; \@{ $class . '::ISA' } };
my $inherits = @$isa;
```

Notes:

1. All classes inherit from UNIVERSAL, but that's ignored unless a class explicitly declares it inherits from it.
2. These methods don't care how the inheritance was declared (`use parent` or some other means).

Comment: well, in the end, I thought I wanted to, then discovered it was somewhat unnecessary, but could not let go of trying to figure out how to do it. Thank you for answering, I have now solved it another way, but still am glad to know.